# Set Icon's position over Imageviews(inside frameLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I am new to android.I have a question that i am trying to put icons over the FrameLayout.
[image]

Now,all the four colored triangular Boxes are the ImageViews in the different four FrameLayouts and all the four Frame Layouts are inside a RelativeLayout.

Now I want to put the icons over the 4 FrameLayouts.I am making these layouts in jaa not in XML.
So,I am not able to put these icons over the particular ImageView(framelayout);
I am using this code to set the position of icons over the particular frame or imageview,

```
ImageView icon = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.wordpress_icon);        
        LayoutParams paramsIcon = new LayoutParams(50, 50);
        MarginLayoutParams IconPara = new MarginLayoutParams(50,50);
       // IconPara.setMargins(500, 500, 0, 0);
        //icon.setPadding(0, 0, width-60, height-60);
        icon.layout(50, 50, 0, 0);
        icon.requestLayout();
        icon.setLayoutParams(paramsIcon);
```

But after all , I am not able to put these icons over the specific place on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try your code with bellow code.

```
                FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(
                            layout_A.getContext());
                frameLayout.addView(imageAndTextLayout);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                            android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT;

                icon.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                frameLayout.addView(textView);
                linearLayout.addView(frameLayout);
```